# Connecting Java and Teradata via java error

Tags: java, teradata

I am using 2 jars :

**1. tdgssconfig**

**2. terajdbc4**

```
Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver");
connString = "jdbc:teradata://" + host + "/database=" + db +       ",tmode=DEFAULT,charset=UTF8,LOGMECH=TD2";
//DriverManager.registerDriver (new   com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver()); 
  DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(120);

this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString, user,password);
```

On my computer which as also installed Teradata **SQLAssistant** the process is working and connecting teradata
but on the server which don't have the software ,the process is failed to connect tera data. I get the following error :

**TERAJDBC4 ERROR [main] com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6_SQL_Connection**

Comment: So the server has the JAR files but not SQL Assistant?

Comment: @Rob Paller   Yes. but should SQL assistant need to be installed in order to connect Tera data through java code??

Comment: No - SQL Assistant is does not use Java. Can you provide more of the log with the error?